# Accidently turned off the Saved to Drafts feature in Outlook Express 6

Tags: windows-xp, outlook-express

In Outlook Express 6 I inadvertently ticked the do not show again box in the "saved to drafts" popup message box when saving a draft message. How do I reinstate the "saved to drafts" popup message box being displayed when saving future draft e-mails.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any way to do this without editing the registry, so **be *extremely* careful!**

1. Close Outlook Express *completely* (make sure it is not simply minimised to the status bar/tray/notification area)
2. `Start / Run / Type "regedit" (without the quotes) / Press Enter`
3. Navigate to:

   ```
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Identities\{Your Identity Number}\Software\Microsoft\Outlook Express\6.0\Dont Show Dialogs
   ```
4. Find `Saved in Saved Items`
5. Double-click it (or right-click / Modify), then modify the value from **1** to **0**
6. Close the Registry Editor, restart OE and test

(Since you're new here, if it works don't forget to accept the answer!)